# What event should I track if I want to know when a user deletes text from an input, even when the user doesn't use a keyboard

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

At the moment i am using JQuery keyup() but if I select the text, right click and delete delete. this doesn't fire obviously. I was going to add another event on focus or blur or whatever until I catch it all the time but it means repeating a lot of code.

is there an event that can detect when an input box is cleared more effeciently?

```
$("#companies_wrapper").find('div.dataTables_filter input:first').keyup(function(){
                    if($(this).val() ==""){ // if no text in input clear the table
                        oTable.fnFilter('');
                    }
                });
```

Comment: About "repeating a lot of code" - you can bind the same handler to multiple events at once: `$(selector).on('keyup change blur otherevent', function(e) { /* */ })`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best way I've found is to listen to as many change events as possible. Here are the ones I use:

```
var _events_textchanged = 'propertychange keyup input paste change';
myJQueryObject.on(  _events_textchanged, myFunction );
```

Put the string somewhere global and you'll be able to update it easily if a new one appears or an old one becomes obsolete.